# Retrieving twitter conversation

Tags: api, twitter

I'm attempting to get all the replies to a tweet ie the replies to this tweet:

https://twitter.com/bbcworldservice/status/309345806123667456

I had this working using something like:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?count=100&since_id=309345806123667456

But I've since discovered that this returns all the most recent tweets instead of all the tweets from this ID onwards. So say that this user is mentioned much more than 100 times the replies to this tweet are no longer included. Rendering it useless.

Can anyone help? Offer any alternate suggestions?

Thanks,
Helen

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue a few months ago at work, as I was previously using their `related_tweets` endpoint in REST V1.

So I had to create a workaround, which I have documented here.
http://adriancrepaz.com/twitter_conversations_api

This class should do exactly what you want.
It scrapes the HTML of the mobile site, and parses a conversation. I've used it for a while and it seems very reliable.

To fetch a conversation...

**Request**

```
<?php

require_once 'acTwitterConversation.php';

$twitter = new acTwitterConversation;
$conversation = $twitter->fetchConversion(324215761998594048);
print_r($conversation);

?>
```

**Response**

```
Array
(
    [error] => false
    [tweets] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 324214451756728320
                    [state] => before
                    [username] => facebook
                    [name] => Facebook
                    [content] => Facebook for iOS v6.0 ? Now with chat heads and stickers in private messages, and a more beautiful News Feed on iPad itunes.apple.com/us/app/faceboo?
                    [date] => 16 Apr
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [thumbnail] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6_normal.png
                            [large] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6.png
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 324214861728989184
                    [state] => before
                    [username] => michaelschultz
                    [name] => Michael Schultz
                    [content] => @facebook good April Fools joke Facebook?.chat hasn?t changed. No new features.
                    [date] => 16 Apr
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [thumbnail] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/414193649073668096/dbIUerA8_normal.jpeg
                            [large] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/414193649073668096/dbIUerA8.jpeg
                        )
                )
             ....             
        )
)
```

Hope it helps,
Adrian.

Comment: The link is broken, is there a backup?